# Accessing context variable (a list) in Django Views in Javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am facing some problems trying to access a context variable in my django views in my html javascript. I would like to access 'unclean' context which is a list and USE IT AS A LIST in my html script tag. Any help is appreciated. Thank you. Below are some of my code:

views.py

```
context = { 
  'unclean' : unclean
       }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use **`{{ unclean }}`**?

Comment: Yes. However, accessing the variable like this in javascript makes it a 'string' type. I need to use it as an 'array' type in javascript for manipulation. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) tag to include a python object as a JS variable in your template

```
{{ unclean|json_script:"unclean-data" }}

<script>
    var unclean = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('unclean-data').textContent);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a demo of latest version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/3.0/intro/tutorial03/), which is similar to your case.

python code

```
from django.template import loader

from .models import Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

**HTML code:**

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I did not downvote, I was just going through the [review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) as someone else has flagged your post as low quality (link only). To prevent this from happening again, I recommend reading the [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer?) help page.

Comment: Thank you! Still I cannot agree that someone else did that, he could write his answer or just remind me. It's a quite simple question.